# how to print date format using dd-mm-yyyy to 00-00-0000

Tags: c

```
printf("Date Order time\t\t: ");scanf("%02d-%02d-%04d", &d, &m, &y);
printf("\nDate order\t\t: %02d-%02d-%04d", d, m, y);
```

this is what happen if I type `1`

```
Date Order           : 01-4227112-0000
```

I want to try this

```
Date Order          : 01-00-0000
```

Comment: ***Always*** check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Or better yet, forget that it even exists. Use `fgets` to read whole lines, then perhaps `sscanf` to parse the line (but still check what `sscanf` returns). That will make input validation much easier.

Comment: @Sen2Jr, what, in the code, set `m` to zero?  Why expect output `00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables corresponding to failed conversion won't be changed by `scanf()`, so you should initialize the variables before calling `scanf()`.

```c
d = m = y = 0; /* add this */
printf("Date Order time\t\t: ");scanf("%02d-%02d-%04d", &d, &m, &y);
printf("\nDate order\t\t: %02d-%02d-%04d", d, m, y);
```